# How to get the factors of a cubic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What are the steps to get the factors of $x^3 + 2x^2 + 4x + 3
?$

I know that $x+1$ is one factor (by using my calculator) but how do you get the entire thing without the calculator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rational root theorem says that if there are rational roots they are among $\pm1, \pm3$.  That is few enough to try and you would find $-1$ works.  Then do polynomial division to find $x^3 + 2x^2 + 4x + 3=(x+1)(x^2+x+3)$ and use the quadratic formula on the last piece.

Comment: How do you do polynomial division?

Comment: Very similar to regular long division.  [Wikipedia has it.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division)  Cubics and higher polynomials in school always yield to the rational root theorem or some other trick.  Not so in the real world, but then you are allowed calculators and numeric solutions

Answer (score 1):

If you know that $-1$ is a root, you can indeed factorize your polynomial by $x+1$. Then you will have something like, $(x+1)(x^2+bx+c)$. Normally, you should be able to find the roots of a polynomial of degree 2 (or I hope !)